# Gennaro multi trapdoor commitment scheme

Tags: commitments, trapdoor

In the Scheme Based on the SDH Assumption (page 11 of the paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-540-28628-8_14.pdf), how does the commitment get revealed with the master trapdoor x?

Comment: Could you elaborate? As far as I understood, the knowledge of trapdoor is not necessary for revealing. It's required only for equivocating.

Comment: What do u mean with equivocating? Isn't the master trapdoor used for someone, other than the sender, to know the committed message?

Comment: Im asking how can u know a if you know x, mathematically.

Comment: No, according to the paper the trapdoor is used to open a commitment to a message M with randomness R to another message M' and randomness R'. I'd read the [full version](http://eprint.iacr.org/2003/214) of the paper since it is written a bit more formally.